# Initialize int with resource defined color

Tags: android, android-resources

I have a resource file where I define colors:

colors.xml:

```
...
<color name="White">#FFFFFF</color>
<color name="Ivory">#FFFFF0</color>
<color name="LightYellow">#FFFFE0</color>
<color name="Yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="Snow">#FFFAFA</color>
<color name="FloralWhite">#FFFAF0</color>
<color name="LemonChiffon">#FFFACD</color>
<color name="Cornsilk">#FFF8DC</color>
<color name="Seashell">#FFF5EE</color>
<color name="LavenderBlush">#FFF0F5</color>
<color name="PapayaWhip">#FFEFD5</color>
...
```

And I would like to initialize int fields in a class with a color **value** from that list (not the color ID, the color value)

```
class MyClass {

   private int color1 = ?????;
   private int color2 = ?????;

   ...
```

Is it doable?
I tried `Resources.getSystem().getColor(R.color.White);` but I get:

12-23 11:22:36.016: E/AndroidRuntime(14646): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0b0016

Comment: where you store color.xml file?

Comment: Use Current Application or component context to call `getResources().getColor(R.color.White);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `getResources()` like below-

```
getResources().getColor(R.color.White);
```

instead of

```
Resources.getSystem().getColor(R.color.White);
```

According to Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getSystem%28%29), `Resources.getSystem()` only provides `system-level resources`, not application-level ones (like the resources inside your strings.xml file).

**Update:** To make context available in your class-

```
public class MyClass{
    Context context;
    MyClass(Context ctx){
        this.context = ctx;
    }
// your other stuff here
// Now you can access the context. like 
/* context.getResources().getColor(R.color.White); */
}
```

Comment: `getResources()` requires a context, which I have not available (no context, nor `getContext()`)

Comment: You need to pass the context via constructor call, and set the context for the class.